# What do I do with the red, lightning bolt pad?

Tags: yooka-laylee

In the last level (Galleon Galaxy), there is a house near Trowzer that contains an elemental puzzle, but it has a red lightning bolt pad next to a door and I have no idea how to open it. I've tried glowing, pounding it, ice, fire, honey, bomb, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the armpit of the hallway that connects the house's two rooms (the pagie and cave room), there is a barrel that contains **an electric battery** (the first one in the game?) Lick the battery to become electric-type and stand on the platform with the red lightning bolt again.